# Buying company shares from NYSE being Ukrainian and currently living in Ukraine

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges, shares

I want to buy shares of the company offered at the NYSE. How do I do that? I am a complete novice at this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Shares are normally bought through a broker firm which is a middleman for your transactions. It depends on whether your brokers firm offer you the choice to trade NYSE stocks.

These are the steps to start trading NYSE stocks

1) Find a broker firm which offers trading of NYSE stocks

2) Open an account with the broker firm which will consist of linking your bank account to this account for cash transfer to buy stocks . You are required to fill in your personal details and W-8form(for tax purposes) to trade US related stocks

3) You will be assigned a remisier and you can start trading online or through your remisier

Note: Assignment of remisier to you is completely optional , it is company dependent . Most broker firm offers you the choice to trade online

Comment: Is there an "online" option of buying shares or is broker a "must"?

Comment: @Dennis sorry for the confusion over the terms , there is a "online" option of buying shares for most broker firms

Comment: Thanks! I'll let you know how all this works in Ukrainian realities soon enough :)